# Stuck in CLI mode

Tags: xubuntu, gui

It all started when I tried to factory reset my computer. I closed the "resetter" app while it's resetting. Now I ended up with CLI.

I tried to install Ubuntu desktop GUI using

```
sudo apt-get ubuntu-desktop
```

but it didn't work. It says that they're unable to fetch archives

I have tried to update using `apt-get update` but it says

```
Reading package lists...Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock -open (13: Permission denied)
E:Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin -RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Use of apt-update: `apt-get [options] command`. You are not providing any command: update, install remove, etc...

Comment: Did you use `sudo` with `apt-get update`?  It needs sudo :P

Comment: Also, if you are using Xubuntu (as the tag suggests), the default environment is XFCE and can be installed using `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize up the comments and clearly state what a new user needs to do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```